# Shell Script: Concatenate string while interating

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script that iterates over directory content and searches for pdf files and creates a string listing all pdf files in it e.g. "pdffile1.pdf pdffile2.pdf pdffile3.pdf".

```
pdffiles=""

#get files in pdf directory
for filename in $1/*; do
    fn=$(basename "$filename")
    #check if file exist
    if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
        #grab only pdf files
        if [ ${filename: -4} == ".pdf" ]; then
            pdffiles = $filename $pdffiles
        fi
    fi
done
```

The thing is this code `pdffiles = $filename $pdffiles` is wrong  and shell script outputs following error message `./mergepdfs.sh: line 39: pdffiles: command not found`.
What is wrong with that line?

Comment: Why not just: pdffiles=$( cd $1 && ls *.pdf 2> /dev/null )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
pdffiles=$1/*.pdf
```

If you like to get them in array form:

```
pdffiles=($1/*.pdf)
```

Output all:

```
 echo ${pdffiles[*]}
```

Output size:

```
 echo ${#pdffiles[*]}
```

Output a single name:

```
 echo ${pdffiles[4]}
```

Comment: To append to an array, you can use `pdffiles+=("$filename")`

Comment: Note that assignment is not a normal shell command and therefore it is not tokenized by splitting it into words at spaces and tabs. There is no = command to be called to handle this. In fact, you can prefix any command with name=val followed by at least one space. So roughly, 1) the line is tokenized on whitespace, 2) tokens are examined for an = expression. 3) if an = is there the token is evaluated and discarded. 4) if no = then the token is treated as a command and the other tokens are all arguments to that command.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use spaces around '=' when assigning:

```
x = 1 # execution of x with arguments '=' and '1'
x=1   # setting shell variable x
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need space around =. This must be a correct line:

```
pdffiles=$filename' '$pdffiles
```